# I want to add the o_id value to the checkbox value attribute. Am not finding out how to do it

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, web-applications, servlet-3.0

I want to add the user.o_id value to the checkbox value attribute. So please help me how could I do that.

```
<tbody>
    <c:forEach var="user" items="${list}">
        <tr>
            <form action="EditServlet" method="get">
                <td><input class="check" name="order_id" type="checkbox" onclick="ckChange(this)"/><c:out value="${user.o_id}"/></td> 
            </form>
            <td><c:out value="${user.c_name}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${user.c_id}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${user.o_amt}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${user.aprv_stat}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${user.aprv_by}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${user.o_date}"/></td> 
            <td><c:out value="${user.notes}"/></td> 
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

Comment: why not simply do `value="${user.o_id}"` ?